# Command Line to update Microsoft Edge

Tags: powershell, command-line, microsoft-edge

I need users to update their Microsoft Edge. I'm aware you can go to settings -> About Microsoft Edge and it will do this. I want a shortcut that opens straight to the edge://settings/help page.

If I drag from the URL to create a shortcut it says "Unable to open this Internet Shortcut. The protocl "edge" does not have a registered program."

If I use PowerShell to stage a shortcut like below it opens Microsoft Edge, but not to the edge://settings/help. Any ideas?

```
$edge = (New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).Createshortcut('\\' + $PC + '\C$\Users\Public\Documents\Source\Quick Tools\Edge Update.lnk')
$edge.TargetPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe'
$edge.Arguments = '-new-window "edge://settings/help"'
$edge.save()
```

Comment: Is this an Active Directory environment with Edge Enterprise and/or Group Policy?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to proceed to *edge://settings/help* automatically, I think you may need to [use WebDriver to automate Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp). We usually use C#, Python, Java to automate Edge, if you need to use PowerShell, you can use [Selenium PowerShell Module](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell) . Please refer to the steps below:

1. Run `Install-Module Selenium` in Windows PowerShell.
2. Download corresponding version of Edge WebDriver from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) (same version as your Edge browser).
3. Put the Edge WebDriver `msedgedriver.exe` into folder `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Selenium\3.0.1\assemblies` (the path is where you install Selenium PowerShell Module, you can change it according to your real situation).
4. Rename `msedgedriver.exe` to `MicrosoftWebDriver.exe`.
5. Sample PowerShell code:

   ```
   $Driver = Start-SeEdge
   Enter-SeUrl edge://settings/help -Driver $Driver
   ```